# Logged but can't access page for logged users?

Tags: php, session, authentication, protected

I'm pretty noob in PHP but I'm trying to exercise. Since yesterday I'm on a problem I can't even understand, I thought my code was correct but it seems wrong

So here is my function to allow pages for logged users only

**functions.php**

```
function logged_only()
{
  if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
  {
      session_start();
  }
  if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {
      $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = "You can't enter this page - not logged in";
      header('Location: login/login.php');
      exit();
  } 
}
```

So It's supposed to redirect me to login page if I'm not logged-in, simple

**login.php**

```
elseif(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)){
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'You're now connected';
    header('Location: ../profile.php'); // user's homepage
    exit();
```

There is some code above and under this, but it works pretty good.

So in this case the script should insert user's informations into his $_SESSION but it does nothing but redirect me at login.php. Also, the "**profile.php**" only contains "logged_only();" and a print_r (when I delete the redirection to login.php) of the $_SESSION, which shows nothing but "*You can't access this page*" (as I'm sending a message via $_SESSION)

Someone to guide me ? Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Place `session_start();` at the top of any script, outside of any conditions, that are - or have the possibility of - using sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe should read about the `session_start()` in PHP: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php)

In short words: `session_start()` starts a new session or recovers the already existing session with the client.

So after each redirect (also to your login.php) you need to call `session_start()`.

There is no need for

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}
```

You should only use

```
session_start();
```

(In both, your functions.php and your login.php) **before** accessing the `$_SESSION` variable.

**functions.php**

```
function logged_only(){    
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
        $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = "You can't enter this page - not logged in";
       header('Location: login/login.php');
       exit();
    }
}
```

**login.php**

```
session_start();
// ... Rest of code
elseif(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)){
$_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
$_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'You're now connected';
header('Location: ../profile.php'); // user's homepage
exit();
```

Comment: Ooooooh thank you it's very clear now !! It's working perfectly now just by adding that little session_start(); inside of my login.php ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Nice to hear that :)
Then you should accept this answer so others can see it